# other options for AWS Textract .Net SDK

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, ocr, amazon-textract, omr

I am working on a C# MVC solution which needs to support the uploading of 1000s of scanned .PDF survey forms onto a system and then extract the data from each survey; in order to extract hand-written checkboxes I need to use the AWS Textract API. More information on my project can be found here: [AWS textract with hand-written checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58886391/aws-textract-with-hand-written-checkboxes)

My problem is when I downloaded the AWS SDK for .NET I noticed that .Textract is not fully available at the minute for .NET

[image]

My question being, is there any other way apart from the AWS .NET SDK that would allow me to implement AWS Textracts checkbox feature into my .NET system? Neither Googles Vision OCR API or Azures Read API support checkbox extraction unfortunately.