# AWS Textract not picking up radio buttons

Tags: amazon-web-services, computer-vision, ocr, amazon-textract

According to [AWS Textract's documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/how-it-works-selectables.html), it is capable of picking up checkboxes and radio buttons. However, I'm uploading literally the most simple example I can think of, clean sheet, clearly space radio button options:

[image]

I tried another version, with text next to the radio buttons:
[image]

When I run either version through the Textract console, and download the `apiResponse.json` (I've uploaded a [Gist of it here](https://gist.github.com/ychennay/1d98984ad4bb7c100429a51ac3283d76)), I find that it only picks up two of the radio buttons (ie. if you search for `SELECTION_ELEMENT`, **you find only two instances, when there's clearly 5 radio buttons.**

I don't know how to make the radio buttons any more obvious. This happens similarly with checkboxes.

Is there anything about radio buttons I'm missing? I feel like I must be overlooking something simple - surely Textract can't be this low-performing in terms of picking up radio buttons?

Comment: Here's an example: [AWS textract with hand-written checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58886591/174777) and the documentation is [Selection Elements - Amazon Textract](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/how-it-works-selectables.html). I wonder if it doesn't recognise "text below circle" formatting?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yep I read that example. I also updated my question to include a version with text next to the radio buttons, and again, it fails to pick up 5 radio buttons.